# How to authenticate WooCommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have generated the consumer key and consumer secret but I don't know how to aply it to authenticate on Postman. This is the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot from 2016-08-17 14-28-18]

The url looks like this: `https://mystore.com/wp-json/wc/v1/coupons?oauth_consumer_key=ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1471440398&oauth_nonce=Qaq8cK&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXw=`

But this is returning error 401:

`{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}`

I have read the [the documentation](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication) but it didn't show any examples.

Comment: Do you need OAuth? Could you use API keys instead? Those are easy to handle.

Comment: @Gant, I throught the API Keys are what I'm  using. Please can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

You can send your credentials via `Authentication` header if your site runs on HTTPS (it should if you're running WooCommerce).

Here's the relevant part of the docs:
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#authentication-over-https